# Getting Error as The JSON DDL request failed with the following error: Cannot de-serialize Partition. The JSON input is not properly formed

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssas-tabular, xmla

I have been getting below error when I try to execute procedure after concatenated ID parameter in XMLA cube partition code.

```
OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "SSAS" returned message "The JSON DDL request failed with the following error: Cannot de-serialize Partition. The JSON input is not properly formed. Check path 'createOrReplace.partition.source.query', line 12, position 126.;After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: 2. Path 'createOrReplace.partition.source.query', line 12, position 126..".
```

--Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dynamic_partitions(@ID AS VARCHAR(10)) AS
declare @xmla varchar(max) = '
{
"createOrReplace": {
"object": {
"database": "TabularProject59",
"table": "FactInternetSales",
"partition": "FactInternetSales_2015"
},
"partition": {
"name": "FactInternetSales_2015",
"source": {
"query": "SELECT [dbo].[FactInternetSales].* FROM [dbo].[FactInternetSales] where CAST(left(orderdatekey,4) AS VARCHAR(10))="'+@ID+',
"dataSource": "SqlServer H-SAIKRISHNAJSQLSERVER AdventureWorksDW2017"
},
"annotations": [
{
"name": "QueryEditorSerialization",
"value": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?><Gemini xmlns=\"QueryEditorSerialization\"><AnnotationContent><![CDATA[<RSQueryCommandText>SELECT [dbo].[FactInternetSales].* FROM [dbo].[FactInternetSales] where left(orderdatekey,4)=2010</RSQueryCommandText><RSQueryCommandType>Text</RSQueryCommandType><RSQueryDesignState></RSQueryDesignState>]]></AnnotationContent></Gemini>"
       }
     ]
   }
 }
}'
EXEC (@xmla) AT SSAS;
```

----Procedure Execution

```
EXEC [dynamic_partitions] @ID='2015';
```

Comment: You don't have the closing double quote after the @ID in the query string.

Comment: @mhhollomon thanks it worked. I have removed double quote before ID and closed after ID.